# The application won’t load

Tags: uber-api

I keep getting a exclamation point in a triangle saying there was a problem on our end 
I’ve tried to refresh still the same thing 
I’ve uninstalled the app then reinstalled it same results 
Not sure on what I need to do to get it fixed

Comment: What app are you referring to please?

Comment: If this is an Uber question and you are an Uber rider or driver, you should follow up directly with Uber at help.uber.com.